# How to talk about a string

Tags: ada

I know that for files we can have *.txt and it will mean all the files with a .txt extension. I want to know if there is something like this for strings for example i have a string A constitutes from many spaces I don't know how many "spaces blabla spaces    " but I'm sure there is blabla and I do this command if A="blabla" then I:=I+1; I will have I=0(because of the spaces).
How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if one string contains another?

Comment: The same site you found the string trim on also has: [String_matching](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_matching).

Comment: Trim was enough for my program but you're right match also could have been useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wildcards" for a filesystem are an example of "pattern matching".

For example, Windows allows simple patterns like "*.txt" or "*.???".

The general term for this kind of thing is "regular expressions", or "regex".  I think you're really asking:

> "Q: Does Ada support string regex"?

The answer appears to be "yes":

- http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-26-2/
- http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/12.html

> GNAT has two built-in packages for dealing with regular expressions.
>   The first, called "Regexp", performs pattern matching using two
>   different standards. First, it supports standard UNIX shell "file
>   globbing" expressions as described by "man bash". Second, it supports
>   BNF patterns as described in the Ada Reference Manual.'

Here are some good examples of the kind of string manipulation you can do with a regex library:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html

Comment: I read your links but could you be more concret i know that i must use the regular expressions packages should I do it like this : if A=" *  blabla * " or what?

Comment: Please look at the last link, a "gentle introduction" to regexes.  In particular, it sounds like you might be interested in the part on ["Trimming Whitespace"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

Comment: I finally found the solution in this link using trim :  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_whitespace_from_a_string/Top_and_tail So thank's for your quick answer.